# MySQL query returns wrong result count between a date range no status completed results

Tags: php

Following is my query,

```
SELECT 
    tbl_inventory.prod_name, 
    SUM(tbl_sales.sub_total) AS sold, 
    SUM(tbl_sales.qty) AS qty, tbl_sales.date_updated, 
    tbl_sales.vat,tbl_sales.sales_invoice
FROM tbl_sales JOIN tbl_inventory ON tbl_sales.prod_id = tbl_inventory.prod_id 
WHERE status='Completed' BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2018-01-27', '%Y-%m-%d')                
AND DATE_FORMAT('2018-02-24 ', '%Y-%m-%d') 
GROUP BY sales_id
```

Comment: It display the prod_name,  sold, qty, date_updated ,vat, sales_invoice but status completed is missing

Comment: Well, `status` is not in your column list between `SELECT` and `FROM`. Just because you have it in the `WHERE` condition doesn't mean it will be in the result. You have to add it to the `SELECT` list.

Comment: your where clause is missing something - a date for the `between` operator to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the schema it's hard to know if this is correct but the query needs a date for the `between` operator to work on  so perhaps the query ought to be more like this?

As the only date I could see in the query was `date_updated between` that was what I used

```
select
    i.prod_name, 
    sum( s.sub_total ) as sold, 
    sum( s.qty ) as qty, 
    s.date_updated, 
    s.vat,
    s.sales_invoice
from tbl_sales s
join tbl_inventory i on s.prod_id = i.prod_id 
where s.status='completed' and s.date_updated between date_format('2018-01-27', '%y-%m-%d') and date_format('2018-02-24 ', '%y-%m-%d') 
group by s.sales_id
```

Comment: SELECT tbl_inventory.prod_name, SUM(tbl_sales.sub_total) AS sold, SUM(tbl_sales.qty) AS qty,tbl_sales.date_updated,tbl_sales.status, tbl_sales.vat, tbl_sales.sales_invoice FROM tbl_sales JOIN tbl_inventory ON tbl_sales.prod_id = tbl_inventory.prod_id WHERE tbl_sales.status='Completed' AND tbl_sales.date_updated BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('$_GET[date_from]', '%Y-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT('$_GET[date_to]', '%Y-%m-%d') GROUP BY sales_id;"); When i add it to my pdf_sales.php

Comment: ? please explain

Comment: in my selecting date i choose start date and End date.. <label class="info-title">Select starting date <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="date" name="date_from" required class="form-control unicase-form-control text-input"/>
                                        </div>   <label class="info-title">Select end date <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="date" name="date_to" required class="form-control unicase-form-control text-input"/>

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to say - simply posting snippets of html does not help